# Why round(15.0)==15.0 is false?

Tags: python-2.7, debugging

1. Input 4 integer `n`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, `x[2]`
   with `n = a*x[0] + b*x[1] + c*x[2]` and `n<=4000`
   find `maxi = a+b+c (a,b,c>=0)`
2. When I ran with `n=3164`, `x = [42, 430, 1309]`. Answer must be 15. But why `round(15.0)==15.0` is false? I found it when I tried to print `i, j, tf, ti, maxi` in line 17:

   ```
   x = [0, 0, 0]
   n, x[0], x[1], x[2] = map(float, raw_input().split())
   x.sort(reverse=True) #suppose x[0]>=x[1]>=x[2]
   maxi=0

   if x[2] == 1.0:
       print int(n)

   else:
       for i in range(int(n/x[0])+1):      #first loop to find a: a <= n/x[0]
           for j in range(int(n/x[1])+1):  #second loop to find b: b <= n/x[1]
               #used math to find equation I found:
               tf = float(i*(1.0-x[0]/x[2]) + j*(1.0-x[1]/x[2]) + n/x[2])
               ti = int(round(tf))
               if tf > n or tf <0:
                   break

               if ti==tf and ti >= maxi: #find satisfactory value
                   maxi = ti

               #print i, j, ti, tf, maxi
       print maxi
   ```

Comment: I don't understand your question, it's certainly returning True, you can try from python console

>>> round(15.0) == 15.0
True

Comment: I ran by cmd. input were 3164 42 430 1309. With i=2 and j=0, ti=15 and tf=15.0. But maxi=0. If it right, maxi=15

Comment: If the output is wrong, the problem is your code, in python round(15.0) == 15.0 but your calculation might have precision issue because of floating point

Comment: I couldn't find any bug. I will try another way. Thanks very much!

Comment: Improved code formatting and title.